# How to control the width of - tr:nth-child(odd)

Tags: html, css

I am looking at using tr:nth-child(odd) to create a style for my datasheets. the code is below:

Now, my only real question is how do I make it so that I adjust the width? I want it to fill a space that is 200px by 400px

The depth isn't an issue since each row will dictate the depth, but the length does matter. The code I am using now only center aligns it, and I can't seem to find a way to stretch the fields. I know I am missing something, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
  tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #4D4D4D}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <table class="test2">
<tr>
<td>Text</td>
<td>Text2</td>
<td>Text3</td>
<td>Text4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>13</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </div>
```

Comment: A table row's width is determined by the width of the table, if specified, and the sum of the widths of the table's columns.

Comment: @Alohci I am asking how to define that, because when I enter in width: 400px; it doesn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Tricks Explanation on TR widths](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/#as-wide-as-they-need-to-be-or-fill-the-container-or-beyond)

The only options would be to:

1. Increase the columns that the row takes up. This could be very fidgety

OR

2. Do something similar to this example here: [Semantic replacement for a table](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/#making-semantic-elements-behave-like-a-table)

As someone who prefers semantic markup, and enjoyable websites... I would choose option 2.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question of alignment. It's center and not to the left.  

HTTP://fearainn.com/Char/Sheets/Core/1.png

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```css
body {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #4D4D4D;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <table class="test2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Text2</th>
        <th>Text3</th>
        <th>Text4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have this and it doesn't fill the width: 

  table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relitive;
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relitive;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #4D4D4D;
}